# add alpha (shade) to plotly express stacked bar

Tags: python, plotly

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df_dict = {'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'columns': ['from', 'moving', 'N', 'total', 'perc', 'helper', 'label'], 'data': [['0', 'no', 29, 39, 74.35897435897436, 'all', '74.4 %'], ['0', 'yes', 10, 39, 25.641025641025642, 'all', '25.6 %'], ['1', 'no', 77, 84, 91.66666666666667, 'all', '91.7 %'], ['1', 'yes', 7, 84, 8.333333333333334, 'all', '8.3 %'], ['2', 'no', 6, 6, 100.0, 'all', '100.0 %'], ['3', 'no', 19, 25, 76.0, 'all', '76.0 %'], ['3', 'yes', 6, 25, 24.0, 'all', '24.0 %'], ['4', 'no', 30, 45, 66.66666666666667, 'all', '66.7 %'], ['4', 'yes', 15, 45, 33.333333333333336, 'all', '33.3 %']]}

df = pd.DataFrame(index=df_dict['index'], columns=df_dict['columns'], data=df_dict['data'])
```

I am using the following code:

```
import plotly.express as px

def pl(dt, color_col, title, facet_col=None,
           color_discrete_map=dict(zip(['4', '0', '2', '3', '1'],['#003898', '#164461','#61B3C1', '#8ED3F6 ','#8DD1C8']))):

           px.bar(dt, x='helper', y='perc', color=color_col, facet_col=facet_col, category_orders={col: sorted(dt_temp[col].unique())},
           color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map, title=title, text='label').show()

pl(dt=df, facet_col='from',
                         color_col='from', title='title')
```

In order to produce this plot:

[image]

I would like to add a shading of the specified color in the `color_discrete_map` with respect to the `moving` column of the `df`, so that the `no`'s are a bit more faded.

How could I do that with `plotly` express ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can access the text font through any of the `px.bar` parameters. However, you can save your px.bar in an object called `fig`, then directly modify the each bar object through `fig.data[0]`, `fig.data[1]`, ... `fig.data[n-1]` for n bars.

The text color for each of these bars can be modified by passing a dictionary to the `textcolor` attribute of each of bar objects `fig.data[0]... fig.data[n-1]`. For example, you could modify the text of the first bar to be red with the line: `fig.data[0].textcolor: {'color': 'red'}`. This lends itself to looping through each fig.data bar object and modifying the textcolor attribute to be the desired color.

The last part is to make your color a shade of the bar color. I am not that familiar with hex color codes, so it makes the most sense to convert each hex color code to an rgb tuple of three values, and find the intermediate color between this value and white. plotly.colors conveniently has the methods `hex_to_rgb` and `find_intermediate_color` so we can use these to convert each of your hex colors to rgb, then find the rgb tuple between that color and white which is `rgb(255,255,255)`.

To be consistent with the way you've structured your program, I put the code setting the textfont attributes in your `pl` function.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

from plotly.colors import hex_to_rgb, find_intermediate_color

df_dict = {'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'columns': ['from', 'moving', 'N', 'total', 'perc', 'helper', 'label'], 'data': [['0', 'no', 29, 39, 74.35897435897436, 'all', '74.4 %'], ['0', 'yes', 10, 39, 25.641025641025642, 'all', '25.6 %'], ['1', 'no', 77, 84, 91.66666666666667, 'all', '91.7 %'], ['1', 'yes', 7, 84, 8.333333333333334, 'all', '8.3 %'], ['2', 'no', 6, 6, 100.0, 'all', '100.0 %'], ['3', 'no', 19, 25, 76.0, 'all', '76.0 %'], ['3', 'yes', 6, 25, 24.0, 'all', '24.0 %'], ['4', 'no', 30, 45, 66.66666666666667, 'all', '66.7 %'], ['4', 'yes', 15, 45, 33.333333333333336, 'all', '33.3 %']]}

df = pd.DataFrame(index=df_dict['index'], columns=df_dict['columns'], data=df_dict['data'])
bar_color_map = dict(zip(['4', '0', '2', '3', '1'],['#003898', '#164461','#61B3C1', '#8ED3F6','#8DD1C8']))

def pl(dt, color_col, title, facet_col=None, color_discrete_map=bar_color_map):
    fig = px.bar(dt, x='helper', y='perc', color=color_col, facet_col=facet_col, 
        # category_orders={col: sorted(dt_temp[col].unique())},
        category_orders={color_col: sorted(dt[color_col].unique())},
        color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map, title=title, text='label')

    ## set fig.data.textfont attribute
    for bar_number in range(len(fig.data)):
        bar_color = hex_to_rgb(bar_color_map[str(bar_number)])
        shaded_text_color = find_intermediate_color(bar_color,(255,255,255),0.5)
        shaded_int_rgb_color = tuple([int(text_color) for text_color in shaded_text_color])
        # print('rgb'+str(shaded_int_rgb_color))
        fig.data[bar_number].textfont = {'color': 'rgb'+str(shaded_int_rgb_color)}
    fig.show()

pl(dt=df, facet_col='from', color_col='from', title='title')
```

[image]